# Ошибка при вызове функции takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python

```py
@client.callbacks.event("on_text_message")
def on_text_message(data: amino.objects.Event):
    nickname = data.message.author.nickname
    content = data.message.content
    chatId = data.message.chatId
    userId = data.message.author.userId
    messageId = data.message.messageId
    send("Привет")

def send(text):
    global chatId
    global messageId
    subclient.send_message(chatId=chatId, message=text, replyTo=messageId)



error from callback <bound method SocketHandler.handle_message of <amino.socket.SocketHandler object at 0x000001870E294FA0>>: send() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 344, in _callback
    callback(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 82, in handle_message
    self.client.handle_socket_message(data)
  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\client.py", line 384, in handle_socket_message
    return self.callbacks.resolve(data)

  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 215, in resolve
    return self.methods.get(data["t"], self.default)(data)
  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 203, in _resolve_chat_message
    return self.chat_methods.get(key, self.default)(data)
  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 232, in on_text_message
    def on_text_message(self, data): self.call(getframe(0).f_code.co_name, objects.Event(data["o"]).Event)
  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 220, in call
    handler(data)
  File "C:\Users\Мой Компьютер\Desktop\bot\aimbot.py", line 39, in on_text_message
    send("Привет")
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `send` у вас объявлена после `on_text_message`, из-за чего, очевидно, вызывается какая-то другая функция `send`, которая была либо объявлена, либо импортирована ранее.

Comment: Благодарю, исправил, но вылезла новая..